# Reactive Extensions / UI cache web request data

Tags: c#, caching, system.reactive, observable, reactiveui

I'm currently fetching data in a view model, by calling out to a web service:

```
_loadDataCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(
        () => Observable
            .StartAsync(ct => _getAllFunction(ct))
            .TakeUntil(_loadDataCancel));
```

`_loadDataCancel` is just an `IObservable<bool>` that acts as a cancellation signal.

Currently, I've got it so that when a vm is navigated to, the load data command is executed.

This is problematic for particularly expensive fetch operations, or when a user just wants to nav away and come back to the state they left the view in (e.g. selected item in a list etc).

What I really want to be able to do, is have it so that the command **always** performs a fresh fetch, but I want to have an additional observable I can utilise on nav-to, which would:

1. Retrieve data from cache if present
2. Use the LoadData observable if the data isn't present (and insert into the cache)

Some research turned up cursory information around things like `Memoize()` and `MemoizeAll()` however, they don't appear to be available in rx (but are in System.Interactive).

Some searching on here, turned up this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12666462/639771, but after looking at the master source for ReactiveUI now I'm no longer able to find `ObservableAsyncMRUCache`.

Is there something I'm missing? I'm almost certain it's going to turn out to be trivial enough, but I'm completely at a loss.

PS: I'm aware that Akavache exists, but it might be slightly too heavy for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like there's a few ways to accomplish this just depending on more factors but is this basically what you want?

```
IObservable<Object> GetFromServer()
{
        //Get From Server
        //Store in Cache
}
IObservable<Object> GetFromCache()
{
        return //returns something from cache or just return null;
}
...
 GetFromCache()
 .SelectMany(result =>
  {
      if (result == null)
          return GetFromServer();


       return Observable.Return(result);
  });
```

There are variations where you could store the result as part of the observable but how that's implemented kind of depends on how you are wanting to expire the cache .. For example you could just create a connected observable that only calls the server once and then just replays the result to any subscribers

```
 GetFromServer()
   .Replay(1);
```